# -PropertyType set as DWord but when Item is created it comes out as a string

Tags: powershell, if-statement, scripting, try-catch, registry

My code:

```
try {
    if(!(Test-Path -Path $registryPath -Value $Name)) {
        New-ItemProperty -Name test -Path HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\Mozilla -PropertyType DWord -Value 2
    }
}
catch {
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $Name -Value $value 
}
```

My Problem: the result comes out as string.

I have tried changing `-PropertyType` to `-Type`.
I have tried changing the capitilation of the word `DWord`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you hardcode the property name `test` first and later in the catch block you use a variable `$Name` ? Also, the property already seems to exist in which case you never reach the `New-ItemProperty ...` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty) say:
*You also use Set-ItemProperty to create and change registry values and data. For example, you can add a new registry entry to a key and establish or change its value.*

With Set-ItemProperty it is also possible to change the type of registry entry from say a REG_SZ (string) value to DWord, so basically all you need is:

```
$registryPath = 'HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\Mozilla'
$propName = 'test'

Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $propName -Value 2 -Type DWord
```

Of course, if you do not have permissions to create or alter something in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE registry path, you will rceive an error.